# Почему не создаётся сессия на реальном сервере (reg.ru)?

Tags: php, mysql, авторизация, сессия, http-status-code-404

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, вот код:

```
function loginIn($p1, $p2){
    global $mysqli;//переменная общего подключения к бд
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$p1' OR pass = '$p2'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
    $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $post;
}
$loginIn = loginIn($_POST['loginUser'], $_POST['passUser']);
    if (isset($_POST['authUser']) and password_verify($_POST['passUser'], $loginIn['pass'])) {
        if($_POST['loginUser'] === ''){
            $errorsAuthUsers = "Вы не ввели логин";
        }
        if($_POST['passUser'] == ''){
            $errorsAuthUsers = "Вы не ввели пароль";
        }
        if($loginIn['login'] != $_POST['loginUser']){
            $errorsAuthUsers = "Неверный логин или пароль";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['authUser']) and !$errorsAuthUsers) {
            $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] = $loginIn['name'];
            $_SESSION['USER_LOGIN'] = 1;
            exit(header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
        }
}
```

На локальном сервере OPEN SERVER всё работает идеально, session_start() в начале файла, в **$errorsAuthUsers** пусто.

Comment: странно как-то WHERE login = '$p1' OR pass = '$p2'. Точно OR?

Comment: А что смущает в данном коде?

Comment: Смущает то что исходя из условия `OR` я  могу указать пароль какого-либо другого пользователя не `p1` и залогиниться под ним. Не говоря о таких замечательных вещах как sql-инъекция, благодаря которой можно вообще под кем угодно залогиниться.

Comment: Приму к сведению! Но только что вводил другие пароли к пользователю, доступ запрещён!

Comment: Изучил ещё раз запросы и изменил на AND

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у вас что-то не так с директорией(указана не туда, или прав не хватает, чтобы писать, ...)
Посмотрите в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692157/session-variables-not-working-php

Answer (score 0):

Решение пришло из файла .htaccess, в котором удалил строчку **Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=lax"** и всё заработало.